# Bus Times Ratnapura to Kandy (Sri Lanka)

Tags: public-transport, buses, sri-lanka

What time do buses run from Ratnapura to Kandy after 10 AM (Please mention the last bus also)?

Answer (score 2):

Departures begin at 11:01AM and then continue through the day at about every 20 minutes.  There are no directs so you'll have to change buses at least once.  Google maps has a great tool for finding bus schedules.  Here is a screen shot:

[image: Google Maps Bus Schedule Screen Shot]